# Sticky Side Nav that Stops Sticking after a Certain Point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wonder how one would make a sticky side nav stop scrolling or stop sticking and lock into place after a certain point. The project page in question is located here:

http://www.tcdiggity.com/new-diggity-menu-22/

As you can see, the little nav with the navs on the left of the menu 'sticks' to the actual page. But if you keep scrolling down, it continues to stick. I was wondering if there would be a way to have it only scroll with the main menu page? I think i have it setup in it most basic form right now using the Fixed CSS tag. Any suggestions would be great! Thanks!

Comment: added fade effect option, so it doesn't disappear so abruptly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want.  You will have to find a value where you want it hidden after.

```
$(window).scroll( function() { 
    var valueOfScroll = $(document).scrollTop().valueOf();
    if(valueOfScroll <= ???)
       $('#sticker').show();
    else
       $('#sticker').hide();
});
```

From testing values on your site, it seems this works good, so it disappears before the end of your main content:

```
$(window).scroll( function() { 
    var valueOfScroll = $(document).scrollTop().valueOf();
    if(valueOfScroll <= 10500)
       $('#sticker').show();
    else
       $('#sticker').hide();
});
```

This is better for a fade effect:

```
var top = true;
var bottom = false;

$(window).scroll( function() { 
    var valueOfScroll = $(document).scrollTop().valueOf();
    if(valueOfScroll <= 10500)
    {        
       if(!top)
       {
           bottom = false;
           top = true;
           $('#sticker').fadeToggle(1000);
       }
    }
    else
    {
      if(!bottom)
       {
           top = false;
           bottom = true; 
           $('#sticker').fadeToggle(1000);
       }     
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Also just as a side note, in your CSS I recommend adding `margin-top:50px` so you side bar doesn't go above that paper background you have for the main content. :)

```
.side-tabs {
    margin-left: -135px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

Per your question in the comments:

```
$(window).scroll( function() { 
    var valueOfScroll = $(document).scrollTop().valueOf();
    if(valueOfScroll <= 10500)
       $('#sticker').css({ 'margin-left': "-135px" });
    else
       $('#sticker').css({ 'margin-left': "20px" });

    if(valueOfScroll <= 10800)
       $('#sticker').show();
    else
       $('#sticker').hide();
})
```

I would say that is "cleaner" because you don't need the second if statement, but looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks! That was the general idea! I added some of my own code using yours to add transitions. Would there be a cleaner way to write the new code with my additions?

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know

Comment: @RaufTür I updated my answer (The bottom is where I added the answer to your question)

Comment: Really appreciate all the help, Great insight and I can honestly say I learned something. Thanks again!